# Why do I get an error when using the easyadmin search bar?

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I don't understand why, only in my 'file' entity I can't use the search bar of easyadmin I have this error:

```
Class "string" does not exist
```

trace:

```
 (line 156)

                    /** @var \ReflectionNamedType|\ReflectionUnionType|null $idClassType */
                    $idClassType = (new \ReflectionProperty($entityFqcn, $propertyName))->getType();
                    if (null !== $idClassType) {
                        $idClassName = $idClassType->getName();
                        $isUlidProperty = (new \ReflectionClass($idClassName))->isSubclassOf(Ulid::class);
                        $isGuidProperty = (new \ReflectionClass($idClassName))->isSubclassOf(Uuid::class);
                    }
                }
                // this complex condition is needed to avoid issues on PostgreSQL databases
```

Comment: Since easyadmin is all about yaml config files, we do need more information in order to help you. Pls provide more exmaples. E.g. search for other entities

Comment: The only difference I have between this entity and the others is that I use the jsor/doctrine-postgis bundle and I have a geog field